# WPF MVVM where to put properties for a TreeViewItem (Is Selected and others)?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, treeviewitem

I'm starting to learning MVVM and not sure if I am properly understand some key concepts.
Let's say I have some ViewModel which has a property `ObservableCollection<CourseModel>` `Courses` and use it to provide an `ItemsSource` to the `TreeView` in my View. CourseModel for simplicity has only one property `Name`. But I need some other properties like IsSelected, IsExpanded etc for displaying it in a TreeViewItem. I may also need to display Course in `ListView` or `GridView` and not sure if it would be right to have IsSelected property in CourseModel.
What would be the best way to extend CourseModel with properties I need?

pseudocode

```
    public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CourseModel> Courses {get;set;}
    }

    public class CourseModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: You answered your own question pretty well. It is the right way to have IsSelected in CourseMode. In fact you might want to reuse IsSelect in ListView and ListBox.

Comment: But is it OK that I may never need IsSelected or IsExpanded anywhere else? sorry)

Comment: I think the proper way would be an ObservableCollection of CourseViewModels because status variables like IsSelected and IsExpanded belongs to ViewModels.

Comment: @LPL, how can I get this ViewModels collection? Should I somehow 'wrap' my existing collection of Models or it's a nasty way and I need something else?

Comment: Yes, this I would do. Wrap your Models when you populate the ObservableCollection.

Comment: You can create a BaseViewModel holding only the list and then you could create two new viewmodels that inherit from BaseViewModel. One would be TreeViewViewModel with IsExpanded property and another can be ListBoxViewModel with some list box specific properties that TreeView doesnt need. It like having wrappers but data in list stays the same.